# How to redirect traffic from http to https?

Tags: http, https

I bought domain with SSL certificate. However, users can access both `http://xxxx.com` and `https://xxxx.com`. How can I assure, that users are redirected from http to https?

Answer (score 1):

In your .htaccess file look for how it's being attempted now and modify/add:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://xxxx.com/$1
```